# Нужны ли запятые перед словом "какой" и перед "в чём"?

Tags: запятые

Чтобы понять(,) какой доильный аппарат подойдёт вашей ферме, нужно разобраться(,) в чём состоят главные различия и сходства доильных установок.
Нужно ли ставить запятые? Если да, то можете объяснить почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(1) **Чтобы** понять (что?), (2) **какой** доильный аппарат подойдёт вашей ферме, (3) **нужно разобраться** (в чем?), (4) **в чём** состоят главные различия и сходства доильных установок.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП), которое состоит из четырех простых предложений (предикативных основ).

Главное предложение (3) связано с придаточном цели (1)  союзом ЧТОБЫ и с придаточным изъяснительным (4) союзным словом В ЧЁМ.

Кроме того, к придаточному цели (1)  относится придаточное изъяснительное (2), связь с помощью союзного слова КАКОЙ.

Запятые ставятся между всеми предложениями в составе СПП.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые нужны, потому что это сложноподчинённое предложение с основами "понять", "аппарат подойдёт", "разобраться", "состоят различия".